# Event handling with kivy Checkboxes

Tags: python, kivy

I'm able to launch an event upon checking a checkbox on kivy, but how to do the same with uncheking?

Comment: you could refer this link https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.togglebutton.html

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
def on_checkbox_active(checkbox, value):
  if value:
    print('The checkbox', checkbox, 'is active')
    # your active Function call
  else:
    print('The checkbox', checkbox, 'is inactive')
    # your unactive function call

checkbox = CheckBox()
checkbox.bind(active=on_checkbox_active)
```